# How do you make something in the center of the page in CSS?

Tags: html, css, center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is this put in the center using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746351/how-is-this-put-in-the-center-using-css)

I have tried so hard to put things in the center in CSS but I just dont get it!

I dont want to use `<center></center>`

So how else is it done?

Comment: What *kind* of centering do you want, and *what* are you centering? Vertical, horizontal, positioning, text-centering... In any case, there are a billion questions on SO about how to to this in a variety of ways.

Comment: Like the center of the page, it seems using <center></center> tags in html on this site is criminal but I have looked at so many sites and used whay they say but it does nothing

Comment: @Wazzzy Whenever text is missing, that usually means that the OP forgot to escape HTML tags. Happens all the time ...

Comment: 'I dont want to use <center></center>' is what its meant to say.

Comment: So if i did use <center></center> around my div tags will it not work on some browsers or something?

Comment: `<center></center>` has been [deprecated](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/html_401/html4-ref/article.php/3460291/Deprecated-Tags-in-HTML-40.htm) so, at some point in time, it will no longer be supported.

Comment: So what is the EASIEST, CLOSEST option to writing <center></center>

Comment: @James Do you want to center a DIV? If yes, does this DIV have a fixed width? If yes, just `margin: 0 auto;` to center it.

Comment: Right its in the center now but all the divs arent inline they are on top of eachother. how do I now make them inline?

Comment: @James You could float them... `float:left;`

Comment: @James, the "easiest & closest" option to `<center>` depends on the target.  In some cases, you can apply a `text-align: center;`.  In other cases, you can apply `margin:0 auto;`.

Comment: I used float but now its all inline and not in the center but left..

Comment: You float each `div` _inside_ the container and then you center the whole container.  You have to first set the width on each `div` including the container.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y3avj/ how do I get them inline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So what is the EASIEST, CLOSEST option to writing `<center></center>`?

Probably something like this:

```
element {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

References:

- Google Chrome stylesheet: http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/css/html.css

  ```
  center {
      display: block;
      /* special centering to be able to emulate the html4/netscape behaviour */
      text-align: -webkit-center
  }
  ```
- Firefox stylesheet: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/html.css

  ```
  center {
      display: block;
      text-align: -moz-center;
  }
  ```

#### Why not to use the `<center>` tag

- It is a "presentational" tag that has absolutely no semantic value.
- It is deprecated. While support for it may continue, it is not guaranteed (this is up to the browser vendor).
- As a presentational tag, it makes very little sense to have to do something like:

  ```
  center {
      text-align:left;
  }
  ```

Presentation should always be delegated to CSS when possible (i.e. almost always).

There are a variety of ways to "center" different things in different ways, but this should emulate the `<center>` tags behavior.

Comment: Thanks! Check out http://jsfiddle.net/y3avj/ How do I get them inline though?

Comment: See my edits at the bottom: http://jsfiddle.net/y3avj/1/ However, you have a lot of conflicting and unnecessary CSS still there and there are better ways to fix this than the quick patches I used. You must understand that "centering something" can mean several things, and any method you use can get screwed up by other seemingly unrelated CSS. Even `<center>` tags an have left-aligned content.

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;`

Comment: `width:50px`??? Also, what about a `<span>` tag - this won't work. We need way more context from OP, but this is a lazy answer regardless.

Answer (score 0):

A quick trick to display elements centered on screen is using negative margin and absolute positioning.

An example:
- We need to display a div 500x200 centered on screen
- html `<div id='center'>this is the content</div>`
- css
`.center { width: 500px; height: 200px; position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; margin-left: -250px; margin-top: -100px }`

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/BxyVb/

or if you want to center it by y axis too then just use a margin top in % value so it will be on sight on small and large screen