# How is this put in the center using CSS?

Tags: html, css, center

Basically I want to put the div tags below in the center of the page. How is this done in CSS? I am having such a hard time doing it what is the best option!?

HTML

```
<div class="tab-selected" id="search">Search</div>
<div class="tab-unselected" id="search">Tags</div>
<div class="tab-unselected" id="search">Recruiters</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tab-selected {
background: #FF00FF;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
font: 13px helvetica;
color: #FFFFFF;
height: 15px;
display: inline;
}

.tab-unselected {
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
font: 13px helvetica;
color: #585858;
height: 15px;
display: inline;
margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
position: relative;
width: 60px;
display: inline-block;
horizontal-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Please do not post [duplicate questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745881/how-do-you-make-something-in-the-center-of-the-page-in-css).

Comment: Sorry, http://jsfiddle.net/y3avj/ Do you know how to make these inline? Thanks!

Comment: Like posting the same question twice, posting the same comment to every single section is abusive to this community.  The answer(s) and every permutation of the answer has been posted more than a half dozen times between your two questions as well as hundreds of similar threads on SO.

Comment: Sorry for posting the same question its because I slightly moidified it and wasnt sure how to show what stage I was then up to and I wasnt familiar with jsfiddle.net until tonight. I dont believe its abusive, I just saw it as the more people I could ask the more chance of getting a reply there is. I am very new to CSS, I am doing this for a hobby because I found an interest in this area. I have looked things up and tried to relate to other questions posted but I am having a difficult time. As you are aware this is a simple question which shows I am not at all experienced. Sorry

Comment: I don't recall how many times it's been explained to you between these two threads, but you have to apply `float:left` to EACH item inside your container.  Then make the container wide enough to accommodate all the items inside.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y3avj/2/ I do appreciate the help a lot but the problem I am having is that now I have put that it is inline but on the left side of the page. How is it then put back to the center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the class `.tab-unselected` in a seperate `div` whose properties would be -

```
.center { margin: 0 auto; float: none; }
```

Now -

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="tab-selected" id="search">Search</div>
    <div class="tab-unselected" id="search">Tags</div>
    <div class="tab-unselected" id="search">Recruiters</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have now got it in the center but they are all now on top of eachother not side by side on the same line, I use display: inline; but that just brings it back to the left of the page. How do I have it in the center and all inline?

Comment: To have them all in a single line, you must have a parent div whose width is sum of the widths of the individual tabs. And them wrap these individual tabs in that parent div.

Comment: I wrapped it but it still has no change?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y3avj/ This is what I mean, how can this be made so its inline?

Comment: @James - You made a quite a few mistakes. Please check http://jsfiddle.net/y3avj/17/ and compare between the two. Would be happy to assist if you have any problems further.

Comment: thanks! I am understanding it a bit more now but I went to apply this to another div and it doesnt work? Please check out http://jsfiddle.net/T5rBU/3/ to see what I mean. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`horizontal-align` does **not** exist. Use `text-align: center` instead. To horizontally center the *element* itself, use `margin: 0 auto;`, which equals:

```
margin-top: 0;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin:left: auto;
```

The automatic `right` and `left` margin results in a centered element.

If you want to vertically align an element, use `vertical-align: center` (this does *only* work on inline elements).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them in a `<div style="text-align: center;">` (or use some other way to apply that style to a containing element).

Comment: jsfiddle.net/y3avj This is what I mean, how can this be made so its inline?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them in a div

```
#center {
margin: 0 auto 0 auto; }
```

Then apply

```
<div id="center"> <YOURSTUFF HERE> </div>
```